# javascript alert - after submit in django

Tags: django

I have an html form in my website it's using django, and I want show massage "javascript alert()" after submit successfully

this is the form:

```
<form action="{% url guestbook-post %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      {% if field.is_hidden %}
        {{ field }}
      {% else %}
        <p
          {% if field.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}
          {% ifequal field.name "honeypot" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}>
          {% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
          {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        </p>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <p class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-post" value="Post" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-preview" value="Preview" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, you need to start by writing some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery with a submit handler:
    $('#myForm').submit( function () { alert('Form Submitted'); });
Not sure how Django handles posts, so you may need to do some further routing within the jQuery call...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a javascript function to the submit handler of the form and have an alert in this function. Something like:

```
<form action="{% url guestbook-post %}" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate()">

<script>
function validate()
{
 // do some validation here to decide whether the post is going to be successful or not.
 if (valid)
 {
  alert("Going to post your data now!");
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false; // form won't post
 }
}
</script>
```